# for loop with 2 Dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 2 DataFrames(DF) and i want to write values from one DF to the second DF
if 2 specific Values are matching. For better understanding here my example:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkuwn2k214h4syk/example.gif

what i exactly want to do is:

if `"item_id"` (DF complete) is matching `"item_id"` (DF Prices)
then write the "item_price" (DF Prices) in "price" (DF complete)

my little attempt is :

```
for (i in 1: length(Prices$item_id){
   for (j in 1: length(complete$text_id) ){

     if ( complete$item_id[j]==Prices$item_id[i])
       Prices$item_Price = complete$price  

     j = j+ 1}
   i = i + 1 }`


Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "pr_listPrice", value = c(0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 10000 rows, data has 591
>   i = i + 1 }
Error: unexpected '}' in "  i = i + 1 }"
```

-> the `"pr_listPrice"` in the Error is `"item_Price"` (DF Prices) in the example

I think this should be not too hard, but I am fighting with the loop since a while :-)

Comment: try `merge(Prices, complete, all.x = TRUE`.

Comment: Oh no thats too easy :-) but it works, Thanks a lot ! @flodel